# Plot zeros of partial sum of zeta Riemann with Maple

Tags: riemann-zeta, maple

I want to plot the zeros of the partial sum of the Riemann zeta function with Maple. Some hint??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could explore around to see where the zeroes might be via

```
partialZeta := proc(z, n) add(i^(-z),i=1..n) end;
ex1 := partialZeta(z, 20);
plots[complexplot3d](ex1, z=0-10*I..1+10*I, view=-1..4, axes=normal,grid=[500,500],scaling=constrained);
```

You will need to zoom in to see the zeroes.  You can also use

```
fsolve(ex1, z, complex);
```

Probably even more useful is the `RootFinding` package, in particular `RootFinding:-Analytic`.

Comment: Thank you J. Carette! I don't know the RootFinding package, very good!